# Merge Sort is not sorting while making changes in the same array

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

So I am solving the merge sort algorithm from leetcode but problem here is that whenever I am trying to implement changes in the same array then it doesn't works.But I try to iterate the elements in different array(EMPTY) then it works absolutely fine.

```
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
   
    while(i<m && j<n)
    {
        if(nums1[i]<nums2[j])
        {
            nums1[k]=nums1[i];
           
                        i++;
        }
        else if(nums2[j]<=nums1[i])
        {
             nums1[k]=nums2[j];
            j++;
            
        }
        
        k++;
    }
    while(i<m){
        nums1[k]=nums1[i];
        i++;
        k++;

    }
    while(j<m){
        nums1[k]=nums2[j];
        j++;
        k++;

    }
```

Here nums1 array doesnt sort while if i do this,then it works fine.In short It sorts the elements in different array not in the larger one provided>

```
  int[] tmp = new int[n+m];                        //Works Fine  Output:-
   for(int l=0;l<nums1.length;++l) {
        nums1[l] = tmp[l];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is attempting to merge nums1 and nums2 into nums1 which will not work for arrays with the current code. Normally nums1 and nums2 would be merged into a third array. To improve performance, merge sort can do a one time allocation of an array the same size as the array to be sorted, then alternate the direction of merge depending on level of recursion for top down merge sort, or with each outer iteration for bottom up merge sort. This requires the code to make sure that the sorted data always ends up in the original array.

Comment: Got it.But why I can't update the same array(nums1) as sorted array ..what's the conceptual error is there ?

Comment: @AlexPandian - it could be done, but nums1 and nums2 would have to be adjacent runs, and you'd have to rotate part of the combined nums1 and nums2 in order to insert an element from run2 into run1.

Comment: Thanks I upvoted your answer .